# PDF xref tables

Tags: pdf

A PDF file can contain multiple xref tables.
When you read a PDF file which has multiple xref tables and save it again. Should the newly saved file contain a single xref table or should all the original xref tables be written again to the file.
(--> indirect related question: when reading a PDF file, should the XREF tables and entries be stored internally in a single XREF table or table per table?)

Reading the 1.3 reference manual doesn't give me a clear answer.

Comment: *Reading the 1.3 reference manual doesn't give me a clear answer.* - The 1.3 reference is both ancient and non-normative. Why don't you look at [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) which is current (if old) and normative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pdf has multiple `xref` tables, it has been incrementally updated. Among other benefits this (incremental update) allows to have kind of versioning feature - one can extract the version of the document before it was updated. Also, when the document is digitally signed, incremental update is the only way to keep the signature(s) valid.

If neither of those reasons is important to you then you could merge the several xref-s into one and probably get rid of some of the now useless (deleted) objects in the pdf, resulting in smaller file size.

As of "should the XREF tables and entries be stored internally in a single XREF table or table per table" - that's an implementation detail of your program and totally up to you. Choose whichever solution works best for you.

Comment: *When pdf has multiple `xref` tables, it has been incrementally updated.* - **or** it has been *linearized*.